# SQL Server Query - Multiple Order By column and per Same Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Sample Table

[image]

I need to sort the record above by `REMARKS` in ascending order, and then by `FIRSTDATE` in descending order, and then by `LASTDATE` in descending order

I do this query

```
select * from tblRecord 
order by Remarks, FirstDate desc, Lastdate desc
```

And gives me this output

[image]

It should be like this:

[image]

**Updated:**
`Startdate` and `Enddate` refer to the actual start date and last date operation of the tenants, What I want is to separate the sorting of tenant per remarks, when ceased, sorting should be based on firstdate in descending order, when started, should be per enddate in descending order.

Comment: When exactly do you have to order by enddate rather than startdate?

Comment: What is `Firstdate` and `Lastdate`?

Comment: startdate and enddate perhaps?

Comment: Well SQL Server does order descending and as you expected. Perhaps rephrase your question to be more specific and why order should be like that?

Comment: I'm thinking when the remark is ceased, then order them by startdate, last startdate first, if remark is started order them by enddate, first ended first? If this is the case then I've got it

Comment: Or order them by startdate descending when it's ceased and startdate ascending when it's started? I have that one to

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply, I was offline earlier, firsdate and lastdate actually refer to the first date and last date of the tenant's operation. What I want is to sort them per ceased and per started, if the tenant's remark is ceased then the sorting to be considered is the lastdate, on the other hand , when it is started, it should be the firstdate, I hope it is clearer now, i am sorry for the confusion

Comment: No, it us the other way around, when ceased, order should be startdate in desc, when started, enddate in desc order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what it is you are looking for seeing as you aren't responding for the moment, I have 2 situations in which I can get the result that you are looking for, 1 of these will deffinitely be wrong or both could be wrong but they both produce the result you are looking for with the test data you provided

Situation 1: You need to order by startdate descending when your remarks is ceased and by startdate ascending when remarks is started in which case you would get this code: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4b5e/15)

```
select * from mytable
order by remarks,
CASE WHEN remarks = 'started'
THEN startdate END ASC,
CASE WHEN remarks ='ceased'
THEN startdate END DESC,
enddate DESC
```

Situation 2: when you have remark ceased you need to order the records by startdate and when remark is started you need to order by enddate, in which case the query would be: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4b5e/11)

```
select * from mytable
order by remarks,
CASE WHEN remarks = 'started'
THEN enddate END DESC,
CASE WHEN remarks ='ceased'
THEN startdate END DESC;
```

Comment: Hi, this worked, case in order by is just what I need. Thanks

Comment: @rickyProgrammer no problem man, next time you ask a question though try to properly state what the case is in your question so people know exactly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: ok, I just wonder if you have an idea in crystal report? because this query is somehow connected to it

Comment: Sorry I have no idea, I've never worked with it, next time add crystal report as a tag on your question so people who know more about it will get to see the question (for me I just look at questions with tag 'sql' because I know a bit about writing queries)

Answer (score 2):

This probably help you using `CASE` in `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT * FROM tblRecord 
ORDER BY CASE Remarks WHEN 'started' THEN Lastdate
                      ELSE FirstDate END
DESC
```